# calling an AccessBean from jsp

Tags: jsp, websphere-commerce

I had attended an interview and interviewer asked me this question:
Can we invoke Accessbean from JSP using usebean tag? do you know if there is some problem when we try to invoke an accessbean from jsp usign usebean tag. I checked in publib but didnt get any satisfactory answer for this.
why do we go for databean in jsp and not accessbean?

Answer (score 0):

I presume the interviewer meant the

```
<wcbase:useBean>
```

tag, and not jsp's useBean.  wcbase:useBean looks specifically for a databean and calls the activate method on the data bean interface, as such it would not be possible to activate an access bean.  You can read more about the tag here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/cdeusebeantaglib.htm